# JNI with c++ keeps crashing on cout, printf and method calls

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am writing my first JNI program in c++, and have made som test methods to make sure everything is working.

The problem is: When I call the method test, it gives very fluctuating results.
Sometimes it  runs forever, other times i get an build error, other times i get a fatal error and an error message. Not only does this happen with printf and std::cout, but also with method calls (then I always get an fatal error. I have **not** included an example with this in the question).
I can't see to find the error. Hope for some help.

I am currently using g++ as compiler, with additional options: -D__int64=int64_t .

**Java class:**

```
public class JNI {
    public static native int test();

    public static native int test1(int a);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filename = "Path-to-lib\\libProjectJNI.dll";
        System.load(filename);

        //Prints 10 - every time - as expected 
        System.out.println(test1(5));

        //Hangs, build fails, or fatal error every time.
        System.out.println(test());
    }
}
```

**C++ class:**

```
#include "JNI.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_project_JNI_test
(JNIEnv * env, jclass obj) {
    std::cout << "PRINT THIS";
    return 10;
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_project_JNI_test1
(JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jint aint) {
    return aint * 2;
}
```

**C++ h:**

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class project_JNI */

#ifndef _Included_project_JNI
#define _Included_project_JNI
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_project_JNI_test
    (JNIEnv *, jclass);


    JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_project_JNI_test1
    (JNIEnv *, jclass, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

**Build error that some time occur:**

```
\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1051: The following error occurred while executing this line:
\nbproject\build-impl.xml:805: Java returned: -1073741819
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

**hs_err_pid### log**

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (0x20474343), pid=33944, tid=3260
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_60-b27) (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.60-b23 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0x71f28]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000002260800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=3260, stack(0x0000000002110000,0x0000000002210000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0x20474343, ExceptionInformation=0x0000000600000070 

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x0000000600000070, RCX=0x0000000000000000, RDX=0x0000000000000000
RSP=0x000000000220f460, RBP=0x000000000220f730, RSI=0x00000003fefac4f0, RDI=0x00000006000000b0
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x0000000000000000, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x0000000000000000
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x000000000000000a, R14=0x000000000220f670, R15=0x00000005696e3030
RIP=0x00007ffb434f1f28, EFLAGS=0x0000000000000206

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000000220f460)
0x000000000220f460:   00000000ffffffff 0000000600000070
0x000000000220f470:   00000003fefac4f0 00000006000000b0
0x000000000220f480:   0000000020474343 0000000000000000
0x000000000220f490:   00007ffb434f1f28 0000000600000001
0x000000000220f4a0:   0000000600000070 000000000000000a
0x000000000220f4b0:   0000000600000300 00000001800ce32c
0x000000000220f4c0:   00000001801523c1 000000000220f480
0x000000000220f4d0:   00000003fefbfec0 0000000180156860
0x000000000220f4e0:   00000006000001e0 0000000000000001
0x000000000220f4f0:   00000000000000b0 000000000220f730
0x000000000220f500:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000000220f510:   0000000000000008 00000003ffa4d5ea
0x000000000220f520:   000077d3bf56b135 00000003fefbfec0
0x000000000220f530:   000000000220f4e0 00000003ffa4cc97
0x000000000220f540:   00000006000000b0 00000003fefac4f0
0x000000000220f550:   00000003fefcbcd0 000000000220f730 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007ffb434f1f28)
0x00007ffb434f1f08:   49 8b d1 44 0f 47 c0 44 89 44 24 38 49 c1 e0 03
0x00007ffb434f1f18:   e8 27 b2 00 00 48 8d 4c 24 20 ff 15 c8 a7 05 00
0x00007ffb434f1f28:   48 8b 8c 24 c0 00 00 00 48 33 cc e8 98 7a 00 00
0x00007ffb434f1f38:   48 81 c4 d8 00 00 00 c3 83 64 24 38 00 eb d6 cc 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000600000070 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000000220f460 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000002260800
RBP=0x000000000220f730 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000002260800
RSI=0x00000003fefac4f0 is an unknown value
RDI=0x00000006000000b0 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R11=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x000000000000000a is an unknown value
R14=0x000000000220f670 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000002260800
R15=0x00000005696e3030 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x0000000002110000,0x0000000002210000],  sp=0x000000000220f460,  free space=1021k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0x71f28]
C  [cyggcc_s-seh-1.dll+0xcc97]
C  [cygstdc++-6.dll+0xba6d1]
C  [cygstdc++-6.dll+0xb0a7f]
C  [cygstdc++-6.dll+0xada61]
C  [cygstdc++-6.dll+0xaff59]
C  [cygstdc++-6.dll+0xb4ee7]
C  [libProjectJNI.dll+0x10b3]
C  0x0000000002375e34

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  gol.s305089.JNI.test()I+0
j  gol.s305089.JNI.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+20
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00000000187fc800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2792, stack(0x0000000018bd0000,0x0000000018cd0000)]
  0x0000000016e97000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=35452, stack(0x00000000186d0000,0x00000000187d0000)]
  0x0000000016e8f800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15496, stack(0x00000000185d0000,0x00000000186d0000)]
  0x0000000016e8d800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=17716, stack(0x00000000184d0000,0x00000000185d0000)]
  0x0000000016e8b000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=26948, stack(0x00000000183d0000,0x00000000184d0000)]
  0x0000000016e89800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9012, stack(0x00000000182d0000,0x00000000183d0000)]
  0x0000000002356800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=24532, stack(0x00000000180e0000,0x00000000181e0000)]
  0x000000000234d800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=35052, stack(0x0000000017fe0000,0x00000000180e0000)]
=>0x0000000002260800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=3260, stack(0x0000000002110000,0x0000000002210000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000016e58000 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000017ee0000,0x0000000017fe0000] [id=4028]
  0x0000000018803000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000018cd0000,0x0000000018dd0000] [id=7356]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 38400K, used 1996K [0x00000000d5f00000, 0x00000000d8980000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 33280K, 6% used [0x00000000d5f00000,0x00000000d60f33f8,0x00000000d7f80000)
  from space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d8480000,0x00000000d8480000,0x00000000d8980000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d7f80000,0x00000000d7f80000,0x00000000d8480000)
 ParOldGen       total 87552K, used 0K [0x0000000081c00000, 0x0000000087180000, 0x00000000d5f00000)
  object space 87552K, 0% used [0x0000000081c00000,0x0000000081c00000,0x0000000087180000)
 Metaspace       used 2783K, capacity 4486K, committed 4864K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 302K, capacity 386K, committed 512K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000011720000,0x0000000011b20000] byte_map_base: 0x0000000011312000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x0000000070aca5b0
 Begin Bits: [0x00000000121d0000, 0x0000000014160000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000014160000, 0x00000000160f0000)

Polling page: 0x0000000000910000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=1102Kb max_used=1102Kb free=244657Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002360000, 0x00000000025d0000, 0x0000000011360000]
 total_blobs=260 nmethods=26 adapters=148
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 0.079 Thread 0x0000000016e97000   22       3       java.util.jar.Attributes$Name::isAlpha (30 bytes)
Event: 0.079 Thread 0x0000000016e97000 nmethod 22 0x000000000246fb50 code [0x000000000246fcc0, 0x000000000246fef0]
Event: 0.080 Thread 0x0000000016e97000   23       3       sun.misc.ASCIICaseInsensitiveComparator::toLower (16 bytes)
Event: 0.080 Thread 0x0000000016e97000 nmethod 23 0x0000000002472950 code [0x0000000002472ac0, 0x0000000002472d10]
Event: 0.080 Thread 0x0000000016e97000   24       3       sun.misc.ASCIICaseInsensitiveComparator::isUpper (18 bytes)
Event: 0.080 Thread 0x0000000016e97000 nmethod 24 0x0000000002472dd0 code [0x0000000002472f20, 0x00000000024730d0]
Event: 0.080 Thread 0x0000000016e97000   25       3       java.lang.String::getChars (62 bytes)
Event: 0.081 Thread 0x0000000016e97000 nmethod 25 0x0000000002473150 code [0x0000000002473300, 0x0000000002473738]
Event: 0.082 Thread 0x0000000016e97000   26       3       java.lang.System::getSecurityManager (4 bytes)
Event: 0.082 Thread 0x0000000016e97000 nmethod 26 0x0000000002473950 code [0x0000000002473aa0, 0x0000000002473bd0]

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (2 events):
Event: 0.028 Thread 0x0000000002260800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BII)Ljava/lang/Class; name or signature does not match> (0x00000000d5f0da00) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u60\4407\hotspot\srÃö×O ?
Event: 0.028 Thread 0x0000000002260800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.prefetchRead(Ljava/lang/Object;J)V name or signature does not match> (0x00000000d5f0dce8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u60\4407\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\j

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.081 loading class java/security/UnresolvedPermission
Event: 0.082 loading class java/security/UnresolvedPermission done
Event: 0.082 loading class java/security/BasicPermissionCollection
Event: 0.082 loading class java/security/BasicPermissionCollection done
Event: 0.082 loading class sun/launcher/LauncherHelper$FXHelper
Event: 0.082 loading class sun/launcher/LauncherHelper$FXHelper done
Event: 0.082 loading class java/lang/Class$MethodArray
Event: 0.082 loading class java/lang/Class$MethodArray done
Event: 0.082 loading class java/lang/Void
Event: 0.082 loading class java/lang/Void done


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff69b060000 - 0x00007ff69b097000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\bin\java.exe
0x00007ffb465f0000 - 0x00007ffb467b1000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ffb45170000 - 0x00007ffb4521d000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ffb43480000 - 0x00007ffb43668000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ffb45850000 - 0x00007ffb458f7000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007ffb452f0000 - 0x00007ffb4538d000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007ffb45530000 - 0x00007ffb4558b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\sechost.dll
0x00007ffb46020000 - 0x00007ffb4613c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007ffb45e60000 - 0x00007ffb45fb6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
0x00007ffb45390000 - 0x00007ffb45516000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
0x00007ffb3e860000 - 0x00007ffb3ead4000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.10586.0_none_8c15ae12515e1c22\COMCTL32.dll
0x00007ffb45a20000 - 0x00007ffb45c9d000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\combase.dll
0x00007ffb43840000 - 0x00007ffb438aa000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x00007ffb45fe0000 - 0x00007ffb4601b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x00000000726a0000 - 0x0000000072772000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x00000000702c0000 - 0x0000000070b49000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007ffb45520000 - 0x00007ffb45528000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007ffb40550000 - 0x00007ffb40573000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007ffb37a00000 - 0x00007ffb37a09000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007ffb412a0000 - 0x00007ffb412aa000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x00007ffb459b0000 - 0x00007ffb45a1b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007ffb404f0000 - 0x00007ffb4051c000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x00007ffb42de0000 - 0x00007ffb42e23000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x0000000072650000 - 0x000000007265f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x0000000072620000 - 0x0000000072649000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\bin\java.dll
0x0000000072600000 - 0x0000000072616000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x00007ffb439f0000 - 0x00007ffb44f4c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x00007ffb42e30000 - 0x00007ffb43475000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\windows.storage.dll
0x00007ffb46140000 - 0x00007ffb46192000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\shlwapi.dll
0x00007ffb42c60000 - 0x00007ffb42c6f000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x00007ffb42d20000 - 0x00007ffb42dd5000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\shcore.dll
0x00007ffb42c10000 - 0x00007ffb42c5b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\powrprof.dll
0x00007ffb42c70000 - 0x00007ffb42c84000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\profapi.dll
0x00000005696e0000 - 0x0000000569704000     C:\Users\active-folder-jni\dist\Debug\Cygwin-Windows\libProjectJNI.dll
0x0000000180040000 - 0x0000000180640000     C:\cygwin64\bin\cygwin1.dll
0x00000003fef00000 - 0x00000003ff055000     C:\cygwin64\bin\cygstdc++-6.dll
0x00000003ffa40000 - 0x00000003ffa5a000     C:\cygwin64\bin\cyggcc_s-seh-1.dll
0x00007ffb2c030000 - 0x00007ffb2c1bc000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
java_command: gol.s305089.JNI
java_class_path (initial): C:\Users\active-folder-java-src\dist\Project.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Users\active-folder-java-src\build\classes
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v5.3;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\;C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin
USERNAME=myUsername
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 10.0 , 64 bit Build 10586 (10.0.10586.0)

CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 60 stepping 3, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, lzcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2

Memory: 4k page, physical 8268824k(3297764k free), swap 9579544k(2510856k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.60-b23) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_60-b27), built on Aug  4 2015 11:06:27 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Sat Apr 30 21:52:33 2016
elapsed time: 0 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `std::cout << "PRINT THIS";` line from `Java_project_JNI_test`?  I'm assuming from the question that the error in the build or at run time disappears?

Comment: Yes. If i remove 'std::cout << "PRINT THIS";' the code works perfectly every time.

Comment: Your problem is most likely that the standard C++ library (and therefore `std::cout`) is not initialized. I remember having similar problems a long time ago. If I remember correctly, I solved it avoiding C++ classes requiring initialization at startup. And I even had to use the matching Visual C compiler version with the matching standard C library version to use standard output at all.

Answer (score 0):

Is it as simple as the C++ side is giving an 8-byte integer address but Java thinks the int type you are receiving is a 4-byte integer?

Java 8 SDK notes say int is 32 bit.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Since you are returning a (probably 64-bit) integer from C++ and then Java is "casting" it as a 32 bit type.  Try changing the return type in the Java side to a long and see if it works.

```
 public static native long test1(int a);
```

Also, why not try the following to see if you can tell where the crash happens?

```
  long n = test1(5);  // get the value into a 64 bit int
  System.out.format("%d%n", n);  // print it separately
```

Comment: The return from test1 is not the problem. As i commented in the java code, test 1 prints 10 to the screen each time, as expected. Also: c++ int and java int is both 32 bit. Source form JNI 8 specification: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html